# How do you get this probability step?

Tags: probability

Question: An urn always contains 2 balls. Ball colors are red and blue. At each
stage a ball is randomly chosen and then replaced by a new ball, which with probability
0.8 is the same color, and with probability 0.2 is the opposite color, as the ball it replaces.
If initially both balls are red, find the probability that the fifth ball selected is red.

I don't know how to get the second line.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: To get from the first to the second line the author just breaks up the problem by considering any possible amount of red balls in the urn after the fourth selection. He then multiplies the chance that this number of red balls occurs after the fourth selection by the probability that the next selection will yield a red ball.

Comment: Yes, all possible amount of red balls are 0,1,2. Then why the first line = the second line?

Comment: What does the notation $P^4_{2,1}$ mean ?

Comment: What may be confusing is that he writes P(fifth selection is red) in the first line while he probably means P(fifth selection is red| X_0 = 2).

Comment: @trueblueanil This is the author's notation for Markov chain. I attach the whole solution. It means after 4 steps (selection here), our urn from 2 red balls to 1 red ball

Comment: @WilliamBit I don't know. I don't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, the development is still here.
\begin{align}
            P( \text{fifth selection is red}) & = \sum_{i = 0}^{2} P(\text{fifth selection is red}, X_{4} = i|X_{0} = 2) \\
            & = \sum_{i = 0}^{2} \frac{P(\text{ fifth selection is red }, X_{4} = i,X_{0} = 2)}{P(X_{0} = 2)} \\
            & = \sum_{i = 0}^{2} \frac{P(\text{fifth selection is red}, X_{4} = i,X_{0} = 2)}{P(X_{0} = 2)} \frac{P( X_{4} = i,X_{0} = 2)}{P( X_{4} = i,X_{0} = 2)} \\
            & = \sum_{i = 0}^{2} P(\text{fifth selection is red} |X_{4} = i,X_{0}  =2) P(X_{4} = i | X_{0} = 2) \\
            & = \sum_{i = 0}^{2} P( \text{fifth selection is red}|X_{4}= i) P(X_{4} = i|X_{0} = 2) \\
            & = 0 P_{2,0}^{4} + \frac{1}{2} P_{2,1}^{4} + 1 P_{2,2}^{4} \\
            & = 0.7084
\end{align}
From lines 4 to 5 the Markovian property is used.